# Problem applying Partial Fractions to the $\arctan(x)$ Integral

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

It is well known that

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+1} \, dx = \arctan(x)+C,$$

and so I wanted to prove this using partial fraction decomposition as follows:

$\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{x^2 +1} \, dx & =\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{1}{x+i} -\frac{1}{x-i} \, dx\\
 & =\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{1}{x+i} \, dx-\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{1}{x-i} \, dx\\
 & =\frac{i}{2} \ln( x+i) -\frac{i}{2} \ln( x-i)\\
 & =\frac{i}{2} \ln\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)+C
\end{aligned}$

but $\arctan(x)$ in logarithmic form is $\frac{i}{2}\ln(\frac{i+x}{i-x})$.

Clearly there's a sign error somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: The two formulas differ by a constant, right? Which is what you expect for an indefinite integral, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why would that be expected though? Also, the constant they differ by changes depending on the branch used, so if you were using this in an indefinite integral it would not work.

Comment: An indefinite integral is only determined up to a constant, Chunky, so if you calculate it by two different methods there's no reason to expect you'll get the same answer both ways. Well, the same, but up to a constant, and that's what's happened here, as Allawonder makes explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any error -- for we have
\begin{align}
& \frac i2\log\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right) =\frac i2\log\left(-\frac{i+x}{i-x}\right) \\[8pt]
= {} &\frac i2\log(-1)+\frac i2\log\left(\frac{i+x}{i-x}\right) \\[8pt]
= {} &\frac i2\log\left(\frac{i+x}{i-x}\right)+\text{arbitrary constant},
\end{align}
as wanted.